# Git: edit unstaged files with both additions and deletions

Tags: git, diff, git-merge

I have checked out a git repo, and overwritten one of the files with a similar (but not identical) file. `git diff` shows a bunch of common sections, but also some additions and deletions (`---` and `+++`). Here is an example with `.emacs`:

```
-;; tab indents
-(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
-(setq-default tab-width 2)
-(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
+;; PDFLaTeX mode and source correlation
+(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
+; (setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
+; (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-source-correlate-mode)

-;; increase default font size
-(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 100)
+;;************************************************************
+;; configure HTML editing
+;;************************************************************
+;;

-;; DEL is deleting the wrong way
-;; https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html
-(normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 1)
+;; Test
+(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . javascript-mode))
+(autoload 'javascript-mode "javascript" nil t)
+(setq js-indent-level 2)
```

How can I edit this unstaged file with both the additions and deletions shown? In other words, I basically want this file as if it were conflicted after a merge, so I can take the parts of both versions that I want.

One approach is to commit the new file in a blank branch, create the merge conflict, and then manually edit -- but there has to be an easier way, especially since `git diff` is essentially showing me most of what I want already (just not the rest of the file).

This sounds like a strange situation, but it  often arises when [managing config files as described here](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/02/best-way-to-store-dotfiles-git-bare-repo/) and setting up a new machine.

Answer (score 1):

I think `git difftool` will be useful here.
You can use it to open the file in a diff tool, such as `vimdiff`,
where you can review the differences and make the necessary edits:

```
git difftool -t vimdiff -y -- path/to/file
```

Other valid `-t` (tool) values include `emerge`, `kompare`, `meld`,
and you can define your own as well.
For more details see `git difftool --help` and `git difftool --tool-help`.

Answer (score 0):

The `git add` command has two options that can be used to edit patches before adding them to the index (see [git-add reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)):

The `-p` option allows you to interactively decide what hunks of changes should be added. It brings up a menu per hunk where the patch can be split and edited among other operations. Using `e` to edit brings up an editor where the diff of that hunk can be edited.

The `-e` option skips the per hunk menu and directly brings up the editor with one big patch for all differences.

The (possibly modified) patch is then added to the index (i.e. the differences become staged) and can be committed directly. This will leave the working copy in its initial state, the edit only happens on the index. The remaining (or newly  added) differences between the index and the working copy can then simply be discarded using `git checkout -- <file>` (or again discarded hunk wise using `git checkout -p`).